# Jest get variable using composition api Vue3 quasar

Tags: testing, jestjs, vuejs3, quasar, vue-composition-api

I'm trying make a test for a variable, but I get `undefined` when I try access the value:

**Component where I defined the variable**
[image]

```js
setup(props, context) {
    const name = ref('Josue');
    return {
      name,
    }
 }
```

**Test**
[image]

```js
import { mount, createLocalVue, shallowMount } from '@vue/test-utils'
import QBUTTON from './demo/QBtn-demo.vue'
import index from '../../../src/pages/Index.vue'
import * as All from 'quasar'
import compositionApi from '@vue/composition-api';

const localVue = createLocalVue()
localVue.use(compositionApi)

describe('Index', () => {
  it('is a Vue instance',async () => {
    const wrapper = mount(index, { localVue })
    await wrapper.vm.$forceUpdate();
    expect(wrapper.vm.$data.nombre).toBe('Josue')
  })
})
```

**Error**

```sh
  Expected: "Josue"
  Received: undefined

  116 |     const wrapper = mount(index, { localVue })
  117 |     await wrapper.vm.$forceUpdate();
> 118 |     expect(wrapper.vm.$data.nombre).toBe('Josue')
      |                                     ^
  119 |   })
  120 | })
```

I got `undefined` from `wrapper.vm.$data.nombre`, but if I use:

```js
data () {
    return {
      name: 'Josue',
    }
},
```

...it works. I dont know how to access a variable when I use the Composition API.

Answer (score 3):

That property would be accessed directly through the `wrapper.vm` (without going through `$data`):

```js
expect(wrapper.vm.nombre).toEqual('Josue')
```